# Difference between "Red Hat Satellite" and "Red Hat Network Satellite"?

Tags: redhat, satellite

Im trying to understand what differences are there between this products. Can someone explain me main differences and what is each one's functionality?

Answer (score 0):

They are the same product. During the lifecycle of Satellite 5, the name was modified to go from Red Hat Network Satellite to Red Hat Satellite. So, if you look for documentation for Satellite 5.5. or below it will be listed under Red Hat Network Satellite (https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en/red-hat-network-satellite/) For 5.6 and later it will be listed as Red Hat Satellite (https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en/red-hat-satellite/)

Answer (score 0):

Red hat network sometimes want to say the internal network of red hat for customers

Red Hat Network (abbreviated to RHN) is a family of systems-management services operated by Red Hat. RHN makes updates, patches, and bug fixes of packages included within Red Hat Linux and Red Hat Enterprise Linux available to subscribers. Other available features include the deployment of custom content to, and the provisioning, configuration, reporting, monitoring of client systems.

Users of these operating systems can then invoke the up2date or yum program to download and install updates from RHN. The updates portion of RHN is akin to other types of automatic system maintenance tools such as Microsoft Update for Microsoft Windows operating systems. The system requires a subscription to allow access to updates. (Red Hat's yum and Advanced Packaging Tool repositories provide free access to updates for Fedora systems.)

On June 18, 2008 Red Hat CEO Jim Whitehurst announced plans for the RHN Satellite software to be open-sourced following the Fedora/RHEL model.[1] Subsequently, project Spacewalk was launched.

Answer (score 0):

RHN channels are obsoleted, RH are using CDN channels.
RHUI and Satellite  are not same product, RHUI intend to manage subscription to cloud customers it can track machines when they come down. Satellite is to manage the whole RHEL infrastructure in a static manner.